# How to enable Microsoft Eva (Cortana's voice) on Windows 10?

Tags: cortana, text-to-speech, voice, text-to-speech-voices, tts

I really like to know how I can enable Microsoft Eva (Cortana's voice) on Windows 10? so I can use it as Text-to-Speech (TTS) voice, since that voice is already available on Windows 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a bit of research I found out how to do this so I came here to share it with everyone else, and here are the steps that will allow you to use Microsoft Eva as Text-to-Speech (TTS) voice.

**Make sure you do the steps correctly or you will break your pc**

1. We need to open `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Speech_OneCore\Common\en-US\` and edit a file named `tokens_TTS_en-US.xml` (*Before we can edit that file we need to change the permission and ownership of that file*)
2. Right click on the file `tokens_TTS_en-US.xml` and go to `Security` tab
   [image]
3. Click on `Advanced` then you click on `Change` where it says `Owner: TrustedInstaller`
   [image]
4. On `Select User or Group` window you type `Administrators` and click on `Check Names` then you click on `OK`
   [image]
5. Now we have to give `Administrators` the permissions we need, click `OK`, now we are back at Properties > `Security` tab (*if it dosent allow you to change permissions reopen properties*), and click on `Edit`.
   [image]
6. While we are on `Permissions for tokens_TTS_en-US.xml` you have to select `<Your computer's name>\Administrators` and click on the check box that is in front of `Full control` and under `Allow` then click on `OK`.
   [image]
7. Now we can edit the file that it's located at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Speech_OneCore\Common\en-US\tokens_TTS_en-US.xml`, we can use any editor `Notepad` or `Notepad++` to edit our file and add the necessary modification, run the editor you picked as `Administrator` by right clicking on the shortcut of your editor and click on `Run as administrator` then use the full path of the file and open it with the editor not by drag or dropping the file and add this to it and then save the file. (**It might ask you to replace or overwrite the file so you need to click Yes or OK**), so its going to look like this [tokens_TTS_en-US.xml](https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/e341ea4d00559723f7681b8a01439c2a) (**Note that this is my version of `tokens_TTS_en-US.xml` and this is just to show you how to do it**)

   > `<Category name="Voices" categoryBase="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore">
   >   <Token name="MSTTS_V110_enUS_EvaM">
   >     <String name="" value="Microsoft Eva Mobile - English (United States)" />
   >     <String name="LangDataPath" value="%windir%\Speech_OneCore\Engines\TTS\en-US\MSTTSLocenUS.dat" />
   >     <String name="VoicePath" value="%windir%\Speech_OneCore\Engines\TTS\en-US\M1033Eva" />
   >     <String name="409" value="Microsoft Eva Mobile - English (United States)" />
   >     <String name="CLSID" value="{179F3D56-1B0B-42B2-A962-59B7EF59FE1B}" />
   >     <Attribute name="Version" value="11.0" />
   >     <Attribute name="Language" value="409" />
   >     <Attribute name="Gender" value="Female" />
   >     <Attribute name="Age" value="Adult" />
   >     <Attribute name="DataVersion" value="11.0.2013.1022" />
   >     <Attribute name="SharedPronunciation" value="" />
   >     <Attribute name="Name" value="Microsoft Eva Mobile" />
   >     <Attribute name="Vendor" value="Microsoft" />
   >     <Attribute name="SampleText" value="You have selected %1 as the default voice." />
   >   </Token>
   >   </Category>`
8. Once we are done with that file its better to restore the ownership of the file by doing the same steps with few differences, go to `Security` tab as we did in step 5 and click `Edit`, as we did in step 6 select `<Your computer's name>\Administrators` but this time you uncheck those check boxs and only leave two of it checked `Read & execute` and `Read` and click `OK`.
   [image]
9. Then like step 3 go and change ownership to `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` after typing that click on `Check Names` and then `OK`.
   [image]
10. Now we need to modify Window's registry click [here](https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/378c0ee9569e2beedffb467de7d817c3/) and then click on `Raw` to download the file once you downloaded the file double click on it and let it apply the registry settings.  [image]
11. Then for the last modifications to registry you need to download [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) or [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) (**I used Process Hacker**), you open Window's settings by pressing this key combination <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and on settings click on `Time & language` > `Speech` then find the process for the settings window `SystemSettings.exe` open it's properties, go to `Handles` tab, look for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Isolated\` right click on it and click on `Open key`.
    [image]
12. It will open the registry key, after `Isolated` key there are some other keys that the name of them are like random generated names but only one of them is expanded right click on it and click on `Copy Key Name` keep that on a notepad or something because we need it, then download this file [MSTTS_V110_enUS_EvaM.reg](https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/7bb04f35017ee3251611193f9110e543) once you downloaded the file you will edit the file and replace `<Needs to be replaced>` with the name that comes after `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Isolated\`, make sure you done it correctly and save it then apply it by double clicking on the file.

**That was all and you just need to reboot your pc**
*Some part of this, the xml content and `Microsoft-Eva-Mobile.reg` comes from this [source](http://jasonpoon.ca/2015/10/29/eva-tts-in-a-uwp/), it didn't had the details it needed so I made this*

Comment: When I use Process Explorer with Win 10 pro version 1730,  I don't get the Handles when looking at the SystemSettings.exe properties.  So had to install Process Hacker to be able to access the handles.

Comment: And I had to use the 'Preview Voice' option in the windows setting speech to populate the handles with the correct data.

Comment: I also used the program TakeOwnershipEx to avoid the headache of taking ownership and restoring permissions of the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Speech_OneCore\Common\en-US\tokens_TTS_en-US.xml file

 http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.18

Comment: And then I had to merge the reg data from there http://jasonpoon.ca/2015/10/29/eva-tts-in-a-uwp/  to have the voice appear in 3rd party apps.

Comment: This worked for me.  All I really did differently (seeing that I am on 1802) was take out all "Mobile" references in the .reg files as none of the other ones had that phrase anymore.  Much better voice.

Comment: @poqdavid a few months ago I could get cortana just by executing a .reg https://superuser.com/questions/1342334/cannot-add-microsoft-eva-mobile-cortana-to-registry-key since it doesn't work any more, did Microsoft change something ? Thanks.

Comment: @user75875 Not sure what changes been made to cortana but you possibly just need to look for new values I personally don't have the time to check what is changed but i will once i get the free time

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I've only German as language, I can't tell for sure if You've enabled the 'real' Cortana voice.
On my PC I've two female voices - one is called `MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaM` and the second `MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaCortanaM`.
If You take a look at `%windir%\Speech_OneCore\Engines\TTS(\de-DE\ in my case)`You will find several files with the prefixes `M1031Katja` and `M1031KatjaV2`

In the registry attributes `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Isolated\********\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaCortanaM]` You will find, that the `MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaCortanaM` voice has Version `11.1.2014.1222` while the other is `11.0.2013.1022`

Finally, I followed Your very excellent guide - but extended it this way that I copied all of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens` 
and also duplicated `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaM` to a new key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaCortanaM`- there I changed all the attributes according to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Isolated\********\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaCortanaM]`
Same procedure with the WOW6432Node tree!

This made the KatjaCortana voice available in the sapi.cpl!

You will notice that both voices are almost equal, but the pronounciation is a bit different - and the the cortana voice really sounds like cortana!

To bring the voice to the new UI, You "just" have to copy the `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Isolated\********\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_deDE_KatjaCortanaM]` key to all those weired named subkeys. You also have to add the `SampleText`attribute as it is missing.

Thanks for Your guide & cheers!

Stephan

Comment: You used the same information of OP who answered himself

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/726436/steph) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/726534/stephan). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)